# Creation of agents in multiple nodes simultaneously

Tags: anylogic

What kind of function can I enter here, that my packages are not only generated at one node, but at 6 nodes which are present in my network.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crxar.png)

Thank you!

I have tried several commands.

I am not sure if you can do it this way or you have to do it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all your nodes, right-click and click "Create Collection".

In your `Node` field, you can now use `randomFrom(myCollection)` and it will use a random node for each.

Note that by chance, this could still send several agents to the same node, you'd have to control this yourself if needed

Comment: What do you mean by "you would have to control this yourself if needed" ?

Comment: Nodes cannot be "full" of agents. You can have 1 million agents move to the same node. If you need "spatial" awareness, you need a different approach